# Redux-Persist not persisting

Tags: react-redux, redux-persist

I'm have a React/Typescript project started with Microsoft TypeScript-React-Starter project:

- "react": "^16.7.0",
- "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
- "redux-persist": "^5.10.0"
- "typescript": "^3.2.2"
- "react-redux": "^6.0.0"

The purpose is to store and persist the Security configuration.

I've follow the redux-persit documentation, but for some reason, the information is not being persisted.

What am i missing?

**redux/Security/Actions/ActionTypes.tsx:**

```
export enum SecurityActionTypes {
  SAVE = 'SAVE'
}
export interface ISecurityAction {
  type: SecurityActionTypes.SAVE;
  payload: ISecurityPayload;
}

export interface ISecurityPayload {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  token: string;
}
```

**redux/Security/Actions/ActionCreators.tsx:**

```
import { ISecurityAction, ISecurityPayload, SecurityActionTypes } from './ActionTypes';

export function saveToken(param: ISecurityPayload): ISecurityAction {
  return {
    type: SecurityActionTypes.SAVE,
    payload: param
  };
}
```

**redux/Security/Reducer/Reducer.tsx**

```
import { ISecurityAction, ISecurityPayload, SecurityActionTypes } from '../../Actions/Security/ActionTypes';

const emptySecurity: ISecurityPayload = { username: '', password: '', token: '' };

export const initialState: ISecurityState = {
  security: emptySecurity
};

export interface ISecurityState {
  security: ISecurityPayload;
}

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: ISecurityAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SecurityActionTypes.SAVE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**redux/Reducer/RootReducer.tsx**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as fromBreadCrumbs from './BreadCrumbs/Reducer';
import * as fromSecurity from './Security/Reducer';

export interface IRootState {
  breadCrumbsState: fromBreadCrumbs.IBreadCrumbsState;
  securityState: fromSecurity.ISecurityState;
}

export const rootInitialState: IRootState = {
  breadCrumbsState: fromBreadCrumbs.initialState,
  securityState: fromSecurity.initialState
};

export const rootReducer = combineReducers<IRootState>({
  breadCrumbsState: fromBreadCrumbs.reducer,
  securityState: fromSecurity.reducer
});
```

**redux/Store/Store.tsx**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { IRootState, rootReducer } from '../Reducers/RootReducer';

import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  debug: true,
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer<IRootState, any>(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default () => {
  const store = createStore<IRootState, any, any, any>(persistedReducer);
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};
```

**src/index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import SecuredRoute from './components/SecuredRoute/SecuredRoute';

import CreateStore from './redux/Store/Store';

const { persistor, store } = CreateStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <SecuredRoute path="/" component={App} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 1):

I installer redux-logger, which helped to understand the problem:
- I had an error on the payload, as i forgot to add the 'security' parameter.

The following changes were made:

**redux/Security/Actions/ActionTypes.tsx:**

```
export enum SecurityActionTypes {
  SAVE = 'SAVE'
}
export interface ISecurityAction {
  type: SecurityActionTypes.SAVE;
  payload: { security: ISecurityPayload };
}

export interface ISecurityPayload {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  token: string;
}
```

**redux/Security/Actions/ActionCreators.tsx:**

```
import { ISecurityAction, ISecurityPayload, SecurityActionTypes } from './ActionTypes';

export function saveToken(param: ISecurityPayload): ISecurityAction {
  return {
    type: SecurityActionTypes.SAVE,
    payload: {
      security: param
    }
  };
}
```